# How can I get two form-group div align in vertically?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get these two divs to align vertically?
No matter what kind of col-ms-sizing I do the two input groups will not align on the vertical line.
[pls check the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lurv.jpg)

Here's my code snippet:

```
<div class="widget-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="form">
        <input class="form-control"  type="hidden"  id="id">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"> fax</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text"  id="name"  name="name">
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"> email</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text"  id="name"  name="name">
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"> QQ</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text"  id="name"  name="name">
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"> wechat</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control"  type="text"  id="name"  name="name">
                </div>
            </div>   
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label"> remark</label>
                <div class="col-md-10 pull-left">
                    <textarea class="form-control"  type="text"  id="name"  name="name"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't a javascript issue. What CSS have you tried? You will want to update your question tags to include `css` and whatever framework this is.

Comment: i have added the answer that you expected

Comment: Ahh got it.... let me update my question.

Comment: have you tried adding row class to your fieldset element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap has a default padding on the col-xx-xx that you use..
so col-md-6 used twice will have more padding than col-md-12 used once..
you could adjust the padding by simply adding an additional inline style.

Just use `padding-left:10px` in your case.. the default is 15 px

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pjoriginal/gmd4z2j1/)

Comment: That's what I want.Thanks buddy!